# importing and accessing drupal website from local and pc's in same network

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, acquia

I installed **acquiva Dev desktop** and imported my drupal website. I can access through **localhost:8083** but gives me "**access denied**" when I access from other pc's in same network.
Can it be done using Acquia Dev Desktop or do I need to switch to other platform 
for installing my drupal website?

Please suggest.

Comment: yes it can be done using Acquia Dev Desktop and found solution  of this problem on this page.
https://www.drupal.org/node/2134281#comment-8170213

Comment: Are you typing in "localhost:8083" on the other PC or the IP address (ie. "192.168.1.2:8083")?